# Equivalent definition of norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is an exercise of an introductory functional analysis course which seems to have a witty solution,but i can't figure it out.
Any hint would be great.

Consider a vector space $K$ and a function $f: K\longrightarrow \mathbb{R^{+}} $ with $f(mx)=|m|x$ for every scalar $m$,
$x\in K$, $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$

the point is to prove that $f$ being  a norm  is equivalent to $$B=\{x\in K:f(x)\leq 1\} $$ being convex.

Ok we only have to prove the triangular inequality for $x,y \in K$ and in order to exploit convexity i thought that $\frac{x}{f(x)+f(y)},\frac{y}{f(x)+f(y)}$ are in $K$ but under which combination do i get the desired result....?

Comment: There should be a typo. It should be $f(mx)=|m|f(x)$, right?

Answer (score 1):

The triangle inequality reads
$$f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y).$$
$B$ being convex means
$$f(aX+bY)\leq 1, \text{ for }f(X),f(Y)\leq 1, a+b=1, a,b\geq 0.$$
Clearly, the triangle inequality plus homogeneity imply convexity. On the other hand, $f(x/f(x))=f(y/f(y))=1$. Let $a=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(y)}$, $b=\frac{f(y)}
{f(x)+f(y)}$,  $X=x/f(x)$, $Y=y/f(y)$, then the convexity implies 
$$f(\frac{x+y}{f(x)+f(y)})=f(aX+bY)\leq 1$$
which implies the triangle inequality by homogeneity.